# How to get the string which is match by strpos() from mainstring

Tags: php, string, strpos

Consider we have a mainstring and a searchstring .

```
<?php   
$mystring = ',1,123,167,778,456';
$findme   = '123';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
echo "The string '$findme' was found in theenter code here string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

if we found 123 then it work fine and give answer string found, but if we give `$findme` value '12' then it also give answer positive.
I want if `strpos()` match a string then this match string is save in a variable like.

```
strpos(',1,123,167,778,456','12');
```

then 123 is store in a variable

```
$string_from_main_string = '123';
```

Comment: Since you are already searching with a given string, what is the point in extracting the same string. You can use `substr($mystring, $pos, strlen($findme))` to get it.

Comment: @air4x as u see i have a  null value in the begining so it cannot give proper string

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `explode` and `in_array` for this kind of task

```
$mystring = ',1,123,167,778,456';
$findme   = '123';

$arr = explode(',',$mystring);
if(in_array($findme,$arr)){
  echo "Found";
}
else{
  echo "Not Found";
}
```

Comment: using in_array the time of execution is increased

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to append the values to original string, if the strpos of value is positive but it is not exactly available in the string :

```
$a = "1,123,456,746";
$a_arr = explode(",", $a);
$findme = "123";
if (strlen(strpos($a, $findme)) > 0){
if(in_array($findme, $a_arr)){


}else{
    $a .= ",".$findme;
    array_push($a_arr, $findme);
}
}
```